# Issue with 'Next' if there is an error 'On Error' ends VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to filter data and copy to new worksheet. I have an issue where if the sheet being created already exists then it will jump to error handling and stop not continue with remaining 'next'. If i move the 'Next' after the error handling it will only loop if there is and error. Is there a way I can have both?

```
Sub SortDataAll()
    ' Sort Data All

    If (Workbooks("Fakturagrunnlag All_1.xlsm").Sheets("All Focal Point Data").AutoFilterMode And Workbooks("Fakturagrunnlag All_1.xlsm").Sheets("All Focal Point Data").FilterMode) _
      Or Workbooks("Fakturagrunnlag All_1.xlsm").Sheets("All Focal Point Data").FilterMode Then
        Workbooks("Fakturagrunnlag All_1.xlsm").Sheets("All Focal Point Data").ShowAllData
    End If

    '~~> Set filter of main data
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Set rRange = Worksheets("Front Page").Range("A7:A21")

    For Each rCell In rRange
        MsgBox "Setting filter for " & rCell

        Dim rList As String
        rList = rCell & "List"

        MsgBox "The list for filter is" & rList

        ' can remove after
        Worksheets("All Focal Point Data").Activate

        Dim v As Variant
        v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range(rList).Value)

        Range("A:BC").AutoFilter Field:=54, Criteria1:=v, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=54, Criteria1:=v, Operator:=xlFilterValues

        MsgBox "Check data is filtered"

        '~~> Create new sheet and paste data
        On Error Resume Next

        With ThisWorkbook
            .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = rCell
        End With

        If Err Then GoTo ErrorJump

        Err.clear

        Worksheets("All Focal Point Data").Range("A1:BC5000").Copy Worksheets(rCell).Range("A1").Paste
        Columns("BB:BB").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Next rCell

    Exit Sub

ErrorJump:
    MsgBox "Sheet already exists":
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Worksheets("Front Page").Activate
    'Range("A1").Select

    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I've used a method where you simply try to use the worksheet and let error control create the worksheet if an error is thrown.

In this, if the *abc* worksheet exists, it is used. If it doesn't exist, it is created then used.

```
sub testws()

    dim wsn as string

    wsn = "abc"

    on error goto make_ws
    with worksheets(wsn)
        on error goto 0
        ...
    end with

    exit sub

make_ws:
    with worksheets.add
        .name = wsn
    end with
    resume

end sub
```

Comment: I would modify your method to take the worksheet name as a parameter and return a bool (true if the worksheet already exists, false if not). By doing this, your method is more generic and you have a bool if you need to do anything different later on if the worksheet was added vs. an existing one was used.